# How to maintain the presence status of user in firebase Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing a chat app in which i have to maintain the user online status and the technology i am using is firebase so how can i do that any kind of help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 8):

***Mabz*** has the right idea conceptually, but I want to highlight a feature of Firebase that specifically addresses your use case.

The trouble that I had run into was updating the RealtimeDatabase with an 'Offline' status. That is, **If the client (e.g. your Android app) is offline, how is it supposed to tell the database?**

**The Solution:** Use `DatabaseRef.onDisconnect()` to set offline status  automatically

```
DatabaseRef presenceRef = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("disconnectmessage");
// Write a string when this client loses connection
presenceRef.onDisconnect().setValue("I disconnected!");
```

[From the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities):

> When you establish an onDisconnect() operation, the operation lives on
>   the Firebase Realtime Database server. The server checks security to
>   make sure the user can perform the write event requested, and informs
>   the your app if it is invalid. The server then monitors the
>   connection. If at any point the connection times out, or is actively
>   closed by the Realtime Database client, the server checks security a
>   second time (to make sure the operation is still valid) and then
>   invokes the event.

A (slightly) more practical example might do something like this when your app first connects:

```
DatabaseRef userStatus = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/<user_id>/status");
userStatus.onDisconnect.setValue("offline");
userStatus.setValue("online");
```

**NOTE: Please note the order of the last two "online" and "offline" status lines. Do not swap it, or else you might have "ghost users" in case the onDisconnect handler fails to register due to a disconnect itself. (which is actually a race condition problem)**

Answer (score 2):

Based upon the information you gave and not considering the performance or bandwidth constraints, here is a way on how I would solve this:

**Using a service and a thread in the Real-Time Database:**

Within the Real-Time Database, I would have an OnlineStatus thread, and then I would save child Key-Value pairs of User Ids and set to their Value to "Green" or "Yellow" or "Red"; this would give me the status as to whether the user is On-line or Away. So that would look like:

OnlineStatus

- User1: Green
- User2: Yellow
- User3: Red

Create a Service that will check if:

- The user is authenticated
- The app is in the background

If the user is authenticated and the app is open, then write to the OnlineStatus thread Current User as a key and "Green" as a Value.

If the app is in the background and the user is authenticated, then do the same but "Yellow" is the Value.

Anything else should result in the color "Red". Also note that if the user signs-off, you may want to write "Red" during that operation.

So this allows every device to update Firebase Real-time Database. What remains is adding a reference to your OnlineStatus location to listen to changes through a ValueEventListener.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use database reference listener “.info/connected” plus disconnect method `dbRef.onDisconnect()` to solve the presence problem of online user.

Here is some sample code:

```
onlineStatus = db.getReference("users/"+user.getUid()+"/onlineStatus");
connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
        if (connected) {
            onlineStatus.onDisconnect().setValue("offline");
            onlineStatus.setValue("Online");
        } else {
            onlineStatus.setValue("offline");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
});
```

You can read more in [this article](https://programtown.com/how-to-build-online-user-presence-system-in-android-using-realtime-database/) on my website.